# Warning: Missing argument 1 when passing parameters from url to controller (laravel)

Tags: php, laravel-4

I am building this website and I want to pass url parameters to routes and from routes to controller, I have searched the docs and google but I can't find solution to my problem

This is an example url

```
locations/search?q=parameter1
```

My route right now is like this:

```
Route::group(array('prefix'=>'search'),function()
{
    Route::get('locations/{src?}','SearchController@locations',function($src = null){});
});
```

and my controller looks like this:

```
    class SearchController extends BaseController {

    public function locations($src)
    {
        return json_encode($src);
    }

}
```

What I want to know is how to pass the parameter to the controller, the code I have right now returns this error

> {"error":{"type":"ErrorException","message":"Missing argument 1 for SearchController::locations()","file":"C:\wamp\www\localsite\app\controllers\SearchController.php","line":5}}

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are mixing the get parameter and the routing variables.. what you'd end up after that route is something like `search/locations/search/` where the second `search` is passed as a parameter and assigned to `$src`

**OPTION 1** 
with your current route what you can do is `search/locations/parameter1` so that the parameter1 is passed to `$src`

**OPTION 2** 
or if you need to change your route to follow `locations/search/parameter1` your route should be like this:

```
Route::group(array('prefix'=>'locations'),function()
{
    Route::get('search/{src?}','SearchController@locations',
        function($src = null){
    });
});
```

then you can use `locations/search/parameter1`

but if you insist on using the get parameter *(locations/search?q=parameter1)*..

**OPTION 3** 
your route should be like this:

```
Route::group(array('prefix'=>'locations'),function()
{
    Route::get('search','SearchController@locations');
});
```

and your controller:

```
class SearchController extends BaseController {

    public function locations()
    {
        $src = Input::get('q');
        return json_encode($src);
    }

}
```

---

**NOTE**
If you are going to make the $src optional on the route, make sure to change the line `public function locations($src)` => `public function locations($src = null)`